# Animator deltaPosition is always 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

In unity.

I have a Animator entity with a Controller.

When the animation state machine play one state in the controller.

The avatar banded in the Animator will be a move form it origin position(i means that state will play a animator not in place).

The transform of the Animator is always 0. And Now, i want to know what the offset position the avatar bone to the transform of the Animator.

From office tutorials http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html

it said that  i can use deltaPosition to Gets the avatar delta position for the last evaluated frame.
But actually when disable Apply Root Motion and modify the OnMoveAnimation() i got deltaPosition is always Vector.zero.

My English is so poor so maybe i did't describe is clear.Hope you can understand.

Comment: Could you formulate this a bit more understandable, please?

Comment: Sorry, firstly i want to describe the question simply as my English is poor....